# Using longRPart package in R

Tags: r, cran, panel-data

I want to use longRPart package in R. But it seems it has been removed from CRAN. Is there any way that I use this package to analyse a longitudinal dataset?

When I enter install.packages("longRPart"), I get a warning message that package ‘longRPart’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

Is there any alternative to use this package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to download the source from the CRAN archive:

http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/longRPart/longRPart_1.0.tar.gz

... and then install the package from the source:

```
install.packages('/path/to/longRPart_1.0.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
```